# Creating new live-templates with import statements in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, code-templates

Here is the Eclipse template that I want to port:

```
${:import(org.apache.log4j.Logger)}
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(${enclosing_type}.class);
```

My current version in IDEA is as follows:

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger($CLASS_NAME$.class);$END$
```

where `$CLASS_NAME$` is configured to use `className()` as its expression.

Unfortunately, I don't find any documentation on adding the import statement. Is there somehing equivalent to Eclipse `${:import(...)}`?

Comment: import for typescript is not implemented yet: see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37425/Importable-state-after-Live-Template-insertion

Answer (score 124, accepted):

According to [this post](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/285215), it is intended to use only full-qualified expressions. I tried it out and this worked for me:

```
private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOG = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger($CLASS_NAME$.class);$END$
```

IDEA automatically shortens it and adds the necessary import statements:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
// ...
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

---

If you want to try yourself, note that you first have to define `CLASS_NAME` as `className()` via *Edit variables*. Also make sure that you allowed your Live Template for Java declarations via *Change* (at the bottom). Here is a screenshot with the final setup:

[image]

Comment: Here I was getting all upset because I couldn't figure out why IntelliJ wasn't _magically_ generating the appropriate imports.  Not only did your suggestion accomplish what I was attempting, this is better than what I was hoping for.  This way, it is more explicit and there is no room for ambiguity. Nice!

Comment: @KrishPrabakar In the question, CLASS_NAME was assumed to be already defined as className(). I added an example now, which should help to understand the answer on its own.

Comment: @PhilippClaßen yes it surely helps now

Comment: Is there a way to do something similar with javascript/typescript ? 
It would be really handy :)

Answer (score 5):

Just to save a little time for new visitors here: the accepted answer now needs some changes.
Go to `Settings -> Editor -> Live Templates`, select `others`, add a template:

```
private static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger($CLASS_NAME$.class);$END$
```

Then, press `Edit Variables` on the left and set expression for `CLASS_NAME` to `className()`.
After all, set context on the bottom to `Java -> Declaration` (and `Groovy -> Declaration` if desired).
Imports will be magically generated on insert.

Comment: @PhilippClaßen well, classpath was changed. I also added more information about template configuring.

Comment: Thanks for the CLASS_NAME trick. It wasn't that much obvious !

Answer (score 1):

Now its possible to add **live templates** with **static imports**:

> You have to check static import in Options

```java
@org.junit.Test
public void should$EXPR$when$CONDITION$() {
    org.junit.Assert.assertThat(null, org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is(org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.nullValue())); 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

For apache commons logging use:

```
private static final org.apache.commons.logging.Log LOG = org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog($CLASS_NAME$.class);$END$
```