# How to add "import" statements from templates in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-snippets

I have defined the following live template in IntelliJ:

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger($CLASS_NAME$.class);
```

I use it to insert logger variable to a class.

Is it possible to define so that template also adds

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

to the file if these definitions are still absent?

Comment: Live template inserts some code in one place. I think what you should use is a file template - to always include the imports and static declaration in every file (you may filter out files with `Test` in their names). Alternatively, you can always add this import in every file and let the `optimize imports` task remove them if not needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating new live-templates with import statements in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190489/creating-new-live-templates-with-import-statements-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 6):

Define it fully in the Live template:

`private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger($CLASS_NAME$.class);`

and IntelliJ should auto reformat the expression to an import. (Assuming you already have the lib JAR downloaded and configured with IntelliJ).

Edit: As comment says: the `Shorten FQ Names` check-box should be checked (which it is by default)

Tested with IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.4

Comment: The `Shorten FQ names` checkbox should be enabled, or it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Now its possible to add **live templates** with **static imports**:

> You have to check static import in Options

```java
@org.junit.Test
public void should$EXPR$when$CONDITION$() {
    org.junit.Assert.assertThat(null, org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is(org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.nullValue())); 
}
```

[image]